# Prove by induction that ∣z1+z2+⋯+zn∣≤∣z1∣+∣z2∣+⋯+∣zn∣ for all n∈ℕ n N .

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, induction

the question is as above, I don't know how to write ic and ih. can anyone give a complete answer? appreciate it

Comment: $|(z_1+\cdots+z_{n-1})+z_n|\le |z_1+\cdots+z_{n-1}|+|z_n|$ now do the same to $|z_1+\cdots+z_{n-1}|$

Comment: yes, but how about the steps.. it looks like a recursion

Comment: @gonda induction and recursion are fundamentally the same thing, that's just terminology.

Comment: |(z1+⋯+zn−1)+zn|≤|z1+⋯+zn−1|+|zn| is it a theorem？

Comment: can  I use it directly?